# Alfresco space user permissions

Tags: permissions, alfresco

I have an alfresco folder (`PARENT_FOLDER`) with more than 300 subfolder, and I want to grant consumer role to certain group (`GROUP1`) and certain subfolder (`PARENT_FOLDER/FOLDER1`), and consumer role to other group (`GROUP2`) and all subfolder.

All subfolders have "Inherit Parent Space Permissions" activated, and parent folder has this space user permissions:

- `OWNER_USER`: `Coordinator`
- `GROUP2`: `Consumer`

The `PARENT_FOLDER/FOLDER1` has:

- `GROUP1`: `Consumer`

With this configuration:

- `GROUP2` can access to `PARENT_FOLDER` and all subfolders.
- `GROUP1` only to objects contained in `PARENT_FOLDER/FOLDER1` (by id), but cannot access to objects from their path, and whit a CMIS client cannot make a getParent(), etc. To make it possible, `PARENT_FOLDER` must have `GROUP1`: `Consumer` grant, and in this case , `GROUP1` could access all subfolders.

I think the solution is *revoke* "Inherit Parent Space Permissions" and specify this user space permissions:

- `PARENT_FOLDER`:

  - `OWNER_USER`: `Coordinator`
  - `GROUP1`: `Consumer`
  - `GROUP2`: `Consumer`
- `PARENT_FOLDER/FOLDER1`:

  - `OWNER_USER`: `Coordinator`
  - `GROUP1`: `Consumer`
  - `GROUP2`: `Consumer`
- Other subfolders differents to `PARENT_FOLDER/FOLDER1`:

  - `OWNER_USER`: `Coordinator`
  - `GROUP2`: `Consumer`

but make it is very difficult because I can't select many subfolders and change their user permissions. I was looking to make it from database model (postgres) but I haven't got sufficient model knowledge to do it. I was looking to make this permission changes from CMIS, but I didn't find anything.

**Question 1**: How can I change space user permissions to many alfresco object at once?

**Question 2**: Do you know other way to do what I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go get yourself the Javascript Console from https://github.com/share-extras/js-console and set  permissions with some basic scripting.
Assuming you picked  the parent as `space`, it should goes roughly like this:

```
space.children.forEach(function(n) {
    // use n.setPermission/removePermission/setInheritPermission
    n.save();// Not quite sure whether save is needed here
});
```

The ScriptNode API is at http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/4.0_JavaScript_API#Permission_and_Security_API.